# let |A| = m, find cardinality of the following set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

|{an arbitary set X is an element of $P(A) : |X| \le 1$}|
My answer is $m + 1$,  since A contain m elements and there are m number of subset of A with only 1 elements plus an empty set, which is a subset of every set. Please correct me.

Comment: Please make the body of the post self contained. The post does not begin in the subject line, just like a letter does not begin on the envelope.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is correct. There's nothing more to it.

Let A = {$x_1, x_2, ..., x_m$},

Then P(A) = $\{\{\}, \{x_1\}, \{x_2\}, .... , \{x_m\}, .... \}$

Clearly, first  $m + 1$ elements are the ones who have cardinality $ \leq 1$